# fraction power vector-norm inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, functional-inequalities

If X is a Banach Space and $x,y\in X$. Then by the definition of a Banach algebra we know $$\|x.y\|\leq\|x\|\|y\|$$ 
and thats how we can have relation for any positive power. i.e. $n\in N$, 
$$\|x^n\|\leq \|x\|^n.$$
Now the question is, what would be the relation for a fraction power? say, $\frac{1}{n}$??  and what would be if power is some real number? not an integer. 
I tried it and got
$$\|x^{1/r}\|\geq \|x\|^{1/r},\quad r\in Z^+$$ and $$\|x^{1/r}\|\leq \|x\|^{1/r},\quad r\in Z^-$$ but I am not sure if it is so.

it may seems a trivial one but its a troublemaker for me.

Comment: what is $x^{\frac{1}{n}}$? or even worst $x^{\pi}$?

Comment: x is some element of a Banach space X. and $x^{1/n}$ is its fractional power.

Comment: If the spectrum of the element doesn't contain (for example) the negative real axis, then you can define the power using a contour integral.

Comment: powers are already defined on spaces i consider. but I want a relation for fractional powers (like above). I tried and got $$\|x^{1/r}\|\geq\|x\|^{1/r},\quad r\in Z^+$$ and $$\|x^{1/r}\|\leq\|x\|^{1/r},\quad r\in Z^-$$. but I am not sure if it is so.

Comment: I have a gut feeling it isn't so in all cases.  It is true for a positive definite operator in $B(H)$.  But I bet if you look outside of that realm, you will find counterexamples.

Comment: yes. but right now I am not considering operators.Operators are defined on such space.

Comment: If you can find one Banach algebra in which it doesn't work, then it probably doesn't work in general.

Comment: yes I know. :( Please suggest me? I am actually working on Power means. If $\|x^r\|$ makes sense then why not $\|x^{1/r}\|$ ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, for $n \in \mathbb Z^+$, the notation $x^{1/n}$ makes sense, then we have $(x^{1/n})^n = x$ and, hence,
$$\|x\| = \|(x^{1/n})^n\| \le \|x^{1/n}\|^n.$$
This proves
$$\|x\|^{1/n} \le \|x^{1/n}\|.$$

Comment: So I did it right?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Note that the case $n < 0$ follows with similar arguments from $1 = \|x \, x^{-1}\| \le \|x\| \, \|x^{-1}\|$. This means, you have the wrong sign in this case?

Comment: Its like, when $r<0$, then $-r>0$. $$\|x^r\|=\|(x^{-r})^{-1}\|\geq\|x^{-r}\|^{-1}=\frac{1}{\|x^{-r}\|}\geq\frac{1}{\|x\|^{-r}}=\|x\|^r$$ i.e. $$\|x^r\|\geq\|x\|^r,\quad r<0.$$ then what would be corresponding fraction-inequality? :/

Comment: Just plug in $x = y^{1/r}$ and take $r$-th root.